# How to implement symmetric key encryption in android to store credentials supporting platform 4.0 onwards?

Tags: android, security, encryption-symmetric

I am working on financial application and I need to save sensitive data in device itself so that user is not prompted to enter certain input. Is there any mechanism by which I can do symmetric encryption in android? Major problem I faced is the security of secret-key used for encryption and decryption.  Also this solution should support android platform 4.0 and onwards. I tried facebook conceal but it is recommended for encryption of large files also my app size was affected by considerable amount as this library uses native plus java code. Please help me to solve this issue.